# Difficulties with JQuery UI Sortable inside Accordion backed by Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

See the jsFiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x5ZtX/4/) for the UI I am trying to construct. First, the user selects a Conference. The Events for the selected Conference are shown in the Accordion, and each Event has Tables which are shown inside the Accordion as a plain html table. The user should be able to drag/drop the Tables and customize their Sort Order. All this is backed by Knockout JS which has worked great so far, but I've hit a block...

The first problem I had was "data-binding" the Accordion. I implemented the custom binding handler solution found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knockoutjs/GEcJ8Pvgbjg), and this seems to work great. However, I can't seem to reliably wire up the sortable functionality for the Table records.

I can't simply call `$(".sortable tbody").sortable();` in the `$(document).ready(function(){});`. Although that works the for the first Conference, as soon as the SelectedConference changes, the sortable functionality is lost. I could add it to the update function of the Accordion's custom binder:

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

            var options = valueAccessor();
            $(element).accordion("destroy")
            $(element).accordion({ active: "h3:last", collapsible: true });

            //TODO: add sortable call here
        }
```

That seems to work, but I'm new to custom binders. Is this innefficient? Are there better ways to implement the sortable functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this project: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about [custom binding handlers](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) they are the right place to put this kind of logic.

However I would suggest that you should create a new custom binding only for the sortable logic because it has nothing to do with your accordions:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        $(element).sortable(options);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it your html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Tables, sortable: {}">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYKAP/2/).

Comment: Perfect! I'm not sure why I was thinking of "piggy-backing" the accordion's custom binding... Like you mentioned, it makes much more sense to do the sortable in a separate custom binding. Works great. Thanks!